# How to use select() function with files

Tags: python, linux, unix, select

I try to understand how `select()` works as a function in Unix.
I have a working sample with socket, but I have a problem with it when using files. When using `select()` on a file object, it doesn't wait - but instead continues to the code afterwards directly.

This sample is working good:

```py
import socket
from select import select

server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
server_socket.bind(("127.0.0.1", 1111))
server_socket.listen(5)

# this function wait when server_socket descriptor will change
read, write, error = select([server_socket], [], [])

# this part print when I use "nc 127.0.0.1 1111"
print(server_socket)
```

But when I try to use the same code with files, I have an unexpected result.

```
import os
import fcntl
from select import select

file_descriptor = os.open('/tmp/test_file', os.O_CREAT)

# lock file? I try to use lockf, other options
fcntl.flock(file_descriptor, os.F_LOCK | os.O_SHLOCK)

# I think that select must wait when the file will be unlocked
read, write, error = select([], [file_descriptor], [])

# prints immediately
print(file_descriptor)
```

Comment: You have one major difference in your code. In the socket example, you place the server object in the `read` stack, where as in the file section, you place it in the `write` stack. And the file object is write:able as soon as you open it. So it's not strange that it continues directly? And I'm not sure the lock does what you think it does, since the process locking it - is you. There for, you're *should* be allowed to write to it.

Comment: I tried to specify the descriptor in the reading field, this did not work.
Then I try to use fcntl.flock in another script, it didn't work either

Comment: You do know btw, that `select` can return empty strings when the object is "ready"? try this: `print(read, write, error)` and you should see empty strings in there. And that's normal, meaning, `select` is doing it's job. Its job is not to block and wait, it's to *not* block and wait by telling you if there is data or not to be fetched. So that you don't call `recv()` or `read()`/`write()` on a blocking object. At least if i recall correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
For for the pipes it works  well

Answer (score 0):

on Unix or os based on it like osx, you should use pipes.

from python doc

> Note that on Windows, it only works for sockets; on other operating
>   systems, it also works for other file types (in particular, on Unix,
>   it works on pipes). It cannot be used on regular files to determine
>   whether a file has grown since it was last read.

Comment: He said he's using Unix tho? Question is even tagged as such. And I'm assuming that paraphrase refers to the use of regular files on Windows?

Comment: @Torxed it said (in particular, on Unix, it works on pipes).  It cannot be used on regular files .... , so paraphrase refers to the use of regular files on Unix, instead pipe should used.

Comment: It doesn't say _It cannot be used on regular files [period]_; it says _It cannot be used on regular files to determine whether a file has grown […]_.